# Mouseleave in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, hover, dom-events, mouseleave

I am new to Three.js and has an experiment I created multiples spheres and tried to apply them a "hover" effect. So when you put your mouse on a sphere it gets bigger and when you leave your mouse from the sphere it get smaller.

Here's what I came up with:

```
    //Scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

//Camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,1000)
camera.position.z = 10;


//Renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setClearColor("#F4F4F4");
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
})

//Orbit Controls
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domELement);

//Raycaster
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();


//Creating my Spheres
//Shape variable
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 10, 10);
//Material variable
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({wireframe: true});

//loop to create multiple spheres
meshX = -10;
for (var i = 0; i<15; i++) {

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  mesh.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  mesh.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  mesh.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  scene.add(mesh);
  meshX+=1;
}

//Light
var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 500)
light.position.set(10,0,25);
scene.add(light);

//Call the Render method on the renderer
var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

//Mouse Over Animation
function onMouseMove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
  for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
    this.tl = new TimelineMax();
    this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.scale, 1, {x: 2, y: 2, z: 2, ease: Expo.easeOut})
  }
}

//Mouse Leave Animation
function onMouseLeave(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
  for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
    this.tl = new TimelineMax();
    this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.scale, 1, {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1, ease: Expo.easeOut})
  }
}

//Event Listener
window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
window.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseLeave);
render();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xaviergodbout/evdxLbk8/13/

Now, the problem I face with this solution is I can't put an animation on "mouseleave".

I also tried THREEx.domevents.js as an alternative. I was able to create the hover animation I wanted but, I was not able to apply it to all of my spheres. Only one is impacted. I wasn't able to create a JSFiddle for this one so here's what it looks like and the code:
[GIF Preview of what happen with THREEx.domevents.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI3BD.gif)

```
        //Scene
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    //Camera
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,1000)
    camera.position.z = 300;


    //Renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setClearColor("#F4F4F4");
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,innerHeight);
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / innerHeight;

        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    })

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domELement);

    //Creating a sphere
        //Shape variable
        var aCircles = [];
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(20, 20, 20);
        //Material variable
        var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({wireframe: true});

        for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            mesh.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) *200;
            mesh.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) *200;
            mesh.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) *200;
            scene.add(mesh);
            aCircles.push(mesh);
        }


        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 500)
        light.position.set(10,0,25);
        scene.add(light);

    var domEvents = new THREEx.DomEvents(camera, renderer.domElement)
    var url     = 'http://xaviergodbout.com/'
    var linkify = THREEx.Linkify(domEvents, mesh, url, true)

    var sphereClicked = false  
    domEvents.addEventListener(mesh, 'click', event => {  
        if (!sphereClicked) {
            material.wireframe = false
            sphereClicked = true
        } else {
            material.wireframe = true
            sphereClicked = false
        }
    })

    domEvents.addEventListener(mesh, 'mouseover', event => {  
        this.tl = new TimelineMax();
        this.tl.to(this.mesh.scale, 1, {x: 2, ease: Expo.easeOut, y: 2, ease: Expo.easeOut, z: 2, ease: Expo.easeOut})
    })

    domEvents.addEventListener(mesh, 'mouseout', event => {  
        this.tl = new TimelineMax();
        this.tl.to(this.mesh.scale, 1, {x: 1, ease: Expo.easeOut, y: 1, ease: Expo.easeOut, z: 1, ease: Expo.easeOut})
    })

    domEvents.addEventListener(mesh, 'dblclick', event => {  
        this.tl = new TimelineMax();
        this.tl.to(this.mesh.scale, 1, {x: 5, ease: Expo.easeOut, y: 5, ease: Expo.easeOut, z: 5, ease: Expo.easeOut})
    })

    //Call the Render method on the renderer
    var render = function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        mesh.rotation.y += 0.01
    }

    render();
```

Any help would be VERY appreciated with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean you weren't able to put an animation on `mouseleave`? Are you getting an error?  I only see `mouseout` on your code example. Also, why do you declare `ease` three times in your tween command? One time is enough for all `x, y, z` attributes.

Comment: Really sorry for the confusion!!... I pasted the wrong code... I've edited my question with the right one. And I would like to thanks you for the tips about the easing, I've updated my JSFiddle!

Comment: I think you can't directly use mouseleave as in html DOM event. There will be more solutions, but i will recommend to count intersections before (old) and while onMouseMove event (actual) and when actual intersections are empty as in the same time first (older) are full, this can be condition which can run your mouseleave function.
If you work with more objects you need to specify which object intersects belong and outwork more complicated schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not subscribe `window.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseLeave);`
because it will not fire when mouse leaves the object.

**Fix #1** – remove `window.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseLeave);`

**Fix #2** – analyze results of `raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);` and handle collection of hovered objects manually, to say which object was un-hovered on every single mouse move.

Updated fiddle you find here: https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/c7t6b1ze/

Fixed code:

```
var hoveredObjects = {};

function onMouseMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

    // collect array of uuids of currently hovered objects
    var hoveredObjectUuids = intersects.map(el => el.object.uuid);

    for (let i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
        var hoveredObj = intersects[i].object;
        if (hoveredObjects[hoveredObj.uuid]) {
            continue; // this object was hovered and still hovered
        }

        this.tl = new TimelineMax();
        this.tl.to(intersects[i].object.scale, 1, {
            x: 2,
            ease: Expo.easeOut,
            y: 2,
            ease: Expo.easeOut,
            z: 2,
            ease: Expo.easeOut
        });

        // collect hovered object
        hoveredObjects[hoveredObj.uuid] = hoveredObj;
    }

    for (let uuid of Object.keys(hoveredObjects)) {
        let idx = hoveredObjectUuids.indexOf(uuid);
        if (idx === -1) {
            // object with given uuid was unhovered
            let unhoveredObj = hoveredObjects[uuid];
            delete hoveredObjects[uuid];

            this.tl = new TimelineMax();
            this.tl.to(unhoveredObj.scale, 2, {
                x: 1,
                ease: Expo.easeOut,
                y: 1,
                ease: Expo.easeOut,
                z: 1,
                ease: Expo.easeOut
            });

        }
    }
}
```